# Router link not working in anchor tag when use dynamic url

Tags: javascript, html, angular

`<a roterLink="/someurl/`+str+`">` + text + `</a>`

here routerLink is not working in angular 9

Comment: words=words+(int==0?'':' ')+ `<a class="markclass cursorHandPoint" routerlink="/hashtag/`+str+`">` + text + `</a>`

using this in pipe and angular attribute is not working init so is there any way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<a routerLink="/someurl/{{str}}">Text</a>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it also**

```
<a routerLink="/edit/{{name}}" [queryParams]="{id: '1'}">Click Here</a>
```